# Computing one value from multiple values in row

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a PySpark Dataframe, and I'd like to add a column computed from multiple values from the other columns.

For instance let's say I have a simple dataframe with ages and names of people, and I want to compute some value, like `age*2 + len(name)`. Can I do this with a `udf` or a `.withColumn`?

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row
l = [('Ankit',25),('Jalfaizy',22),('saurabh',20),('Bala',26)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
people = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(name=x[0], age=int(x[1])))
schemaPeople = sqlContext.createDataFrame(people)
display(schemaPeople)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an way to do this with `@udf`:

```py
@udf
def complex_op(age, name):
    return age*2 + len(name)

schemaPeople.withColumn(
    "my_column",
    lit(complex_op(schemaPeople["age"], schemaPeople["name"]))
    )
```

Comment: it works but it is not efficient. UDF are way much slower that built-in functions. And your return type is wrong. Your UDF returns a string where it should return an Int.

Comment: Yes I used a simple example but in my case I'm computing a string value, I should have chosen a better example.

Answer (score 3):

Use `withColumn`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

schemaPeople.withColumn(
    "my_column",
    F.col("age")*2 + F.length(F.col("name"))
).show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I did not find a way to use more complicated functions, like substituting some letters in "name", or more complex operations with age. I used `@udf`

Comment: @BeChillerToo all the functions are available in the official doc : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm computing a complex value which, I believe, can't be computed with this limited set of functions. I do something like that `if df["A"].startswith("bla") then return df["A"].replace('a', 'b') else return open(df["B"].read())`

Comment: The `open(df["B"].read())` won't work. You are executing your UDF on the worker side. There won't be any B-file to open there I think ... or you're copying your file on each worker, which is also not a solution.

Comment: I'm executing the code on Databricks cluster, which uses dbfs. I tried it and it worked